# Comparing Python dicts with floating point values included

Tags: python

I want to compare a pair of dictionaries and using 'fuzzy' floating point comparison or better yet use `numpy.allclose()` to do so.  However, using the default `==` or `!=` in Python for dicts doesn't do this.

I was wondering if there was a way to change the floating point comparison operation (probably using a context manager for safe cleanup).

I believe an example will help here.  I have a deeply nested dict that contains all sorts of values.  Some of these values are floating point values.  I know there are tons of pitfalls for 'comparing' floating point values, etc.

```
d1 = {'a': {'b': 1.123456}}
d2 = {'a': {'b': 1.1234578}}
```

I would like to use `!=` to compare these two dicts and have it return `True` if the only differences are floating point numbers within a certain range.  For example, do not count the values different if the are **close** (not sure the precision I want yet).

I suppose I could recursively go through the dicts myself and manually just use `numpy.allclose()` for floating point values and fall back to the normal equality testing for all other types, etc.  However, this is a bit tricky and error prone.  I do think this would be an acceptable solution, and I'd love to see one like it.  Hopefully there is something more elegant though.

The elegant solution in my head would look something like the following.  However, I don't know if anything like this is even possible:

```
with hacked_float_compare:
    result = d1 != d2
```

Thus, inside this context manager I would be replacing the floating point comparison (just for standard `float()` values with either my own comparison or `numpy.allclose()`.

Again, I'm not sure this is possible because monkey patching `float()` can't really be done since it's written in `C`.  I'd also like to avoid having to change every floating point value in the dicts to my own float class that has a `__eq__()`.  Maybe this is the **best** way though?

Comment: One option would be to create a wrapper for float and and override `__eq__` there.

Comment: But you'd need to create all your floats with `fuzzyfloat(0.5)`, etc.

Comment: Right.  I know this approach works, just didn't want to have to use a special object/class if I could avoid it.  I really only need the comparison to be 'fuzzy' in this one instance.  This is why I was hoping to use a context manager and just go into a different 'mode' for limited amount of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avoid subclassing built-in types. You'll regret it when you find out your objects have changed type for some unknown reason. Use delegation instead. For example:

```
import operator as op


class FuzzyDict(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable=(), float_eq=op.eq):
        self._float_eq = float_eq
        self._dict = dict(iterable)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._dict[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self._dict[key] = val

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._dict)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._dict)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._dict

    def __eq__(self, other):
        def compare(a, b):
            if isinstance(a, float) and isinstance(b, float):
                return self._float_eq(a, b)
            else:
                return a == b
        try:
            if len(self) != len(other):
                return False
            for key in self:
                if not compare(self[key], other[key]):
                    return False
            return True
        except Exception:
            return False

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # free features borrowed from dict
        attr_val = getattr(self._dict, attr)
        if callable(attr_val):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                result = attr_val(*args, **kwargs)
                if isinstance(result, dict):
                    return FuzzyDict(result, self._float_eq)
                return result
            return wrapper
        return attr_val
```

And an example usage:

```
>>> def float_eq(a, b):
...     return abs(a - b) < 0.01
... 
>>> A = FuzzyDict(float_eq=float_eq)
>>> B = FuzzyDict(float_eq=float_eq)
>>> A['a'] = 2.345
>>> A['b'] = 'a string'
>>> B['a'] = 2.345
>>> B['b'] = 'a string'
>>> B['a'] = 2.3445
>>> A == B
True
>>> B['a'] = 234.55
>>> A == B
False
>>> B['a'] = 2.345
>>> B['b'] = 'a strin'
>>> A == B
False
```

And they work even when nested:

```
>>> A['nested'] = FuzzyDict(float_eq=float_eq)
>>> A['nested']['a'] = 17.32
>>> B['nested'] = FuzzyDict(float_eq=float_eq)
>>> B['nested']['a'] = 17.321
>>> B['b'] = 'a string'   # changed before
>>> A == B
True
>>> B['nested']['a'] = 17.34
>>> A == B
False
```

A complete replacement for `dict` would require a bit more code and probably some testing to see how robust it is, but even the above solution provides many of the `dict` features(e.g. `copy`, `setdefault`, `get`, `update` etc.)

---

Regarding why you shouldn't subclass a built-in.

This solution seems easy and correct, but it generally isn't.
First of all, even though you can subclass built-in types, this does not mean that they were written to be used as subclasses, so you may find out that to make something work you have to write more code than you thought.

Also, you'll probably want to use the built-in methods, but these methods will return an instance of the built-in type and not an instance of your class, which means that you have to reimplement every single method of the type. Also, you sometimes have to implement other methods that weren't implemented in the built-in.

For example, subclassing `list` you may think that, since `list` implements only `__iadd__` and `__add__` you'll be safe reimplementing these two methods, but you are wrong! You must also implement `__radd__`, otherwise expressions like:

```
[1,2,3] + MyList([1,2,3])
```

Would return a normal `list` and not `MyList`.

In summary, subclassing a built-in has a lot more consequences than what you may think at the beginning and it may introduce some unpredictable bugs due to change of types or behaviour that you did not expect. Debugging also becomes harder because you can't simply print the instances of the objects in the log, the representation would be correct! You really must check for the class of all the objects around to catch this subtle bugs.

In your specific situation, if you plan to convert the dictionaries only inside a single method, then you may avoid most disadvantages of subclassing `dict`, but at that point why don't you simply write a function and compare the `dict`s with it?
This should work well, except if you want to pass the `dict`s to a library function that does the comparison.

Comment: This looks pretty good.  However, in my case I think just subclassing `dict` might be ok.  I just want to convert the dicts locally to do this compare.  So, this new class will only ever be used internally to a single method.  Does this make sense and seem reasonable?

Comment: However, this solution won't return False if the `other` dict has keys that are not in the first dict.  So this solution changes the semantics of comparing dicts by more than just the floating point comparison, right?

Comment: @durden2.0 I did change it slightly from when I first posted it, and I thought it was okay. Before I first checked `sorted(self) == sorted(other)` which get read of this difference, but I think also the above is okay. Because if the number of keys is different, then that is caught by comparing the lengths, and after that I check every key in `self`, and if it is not in `other` a `KeyError` is raised which is caught by the `except Exception` that correctly returns `False`, so it should be okay.
Anyway, if the change is guaranteed to be only in a method maybe subclassing `dict` is okay.

Comment: @durden2.0 I checked python's `dict.__eq__` implementation and they do a similar thing: check the lengths and the iterate over the table of a dict and check the entry in other dict, so I'd say the above implementation is correct.

Comment: ok that makes sense.  Thanks for checking.  On a related note, why do I have to implement `__ne__` as well as `__eq__`?  I thought CPython would just call `__eq__` and invert it, but doesn't seem to be the case.  I even looked at the CPython source and I'm missing something.  When using `!=` the overridden `__eq__` is not called (in Python 2.7.3 at least).  Can you point me to how this works in the CPython source?

Comment: @durden2.0 If you want to see that implementation you should check `PyObject_RichCompare` in `Objects/object.c`, and maybe checking the `COMPARE_OP` bytecode in `Python/ceval.c`. Python does not force any relationship between comparison operators, as stated in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__), so he can't simply assume that for the object you define it makes sense to have `__ne__` as negation of `__eq__`.

Comment: Thanks!  Also, could you elaborate on what you meant by 'subclassing built-in types is bad,' or point me to some material.  That seems useful to read/think about.

Comment: you are right.  In my scenario there is no need to sublcass anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, I think in my situation subclassing was not the best way.  I've worked up a solution that I will most likely use [here](https://gist.github.com/4236551).

This is not the accepted answer since it was a collaborative approach based on what I learned from this thread.  Just wanted a 'solution' that others could benefit from.

Answer (score 1):

To override a comparison operator, you need to define a derived class that uses a different operator. So you can't do it the way you suggest. What you could do is derive a "fuzzy float" class (as @Null) suggested, or derive and class from `dict` and specify that it uses fuzzy comparison on floats:

```
class fuzzydict(dict):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Manually compare each element of `self` with `other`.
           Float values are compared up to reasonable precision."""
```

You'll have to churn through the logic of dictionary comparison yourself, and it probably won't be as fast as the built-in comparison, but you'll be able to write `dict1 == dict2` in your code. Just make sure to use `fuzzydict` instead of `dict` for all (nested) dictionaries that might contain floats.

I should add, however, that you're risking indeterminacy: Your dictionaries will compare equal but contain slightly different numbers, so subsquent calculations could give you results that do *not* compare equal, depending on which dictionary you use. In my opinion a safer (and saner) approach would be to round your floats when you insert them in the dictionary, so that they compare strictly equal.

Comment: Yes, this will also work.  However, I don't see much benefit to making my own dict class and putting the comparison code in the dict's `__eq__`.  This exact same code could just be a method that takes two dicts.  Then I don't have to use this new type of dict everywhere or convert existing dicts, etc.  Again, this solution would be fine if I was doing this in a lot of places.  However, there is just one area where this comparison matters.

Comment: Also, doing calculations with these floating point numbers is tricky anyway just because floating point representation, etc.  In addition, in my scenario I really don't mind that these numbers are within a range of each other.  This will not cause any strange operations down the road.  It's just a very limited area of code I want to apply this to.

Comment: Python's dict comparison is recursive. If you derive a class, python will handle the recursion and you only have to implement the flat logic: Checking for missing or extra keys, and comparing the values.

Comment: I'm confused.  The arguments to dict `__eq__` are self (dict on left side of operator) and another dict.  What if the dicts are nested?  Maybe a code example would help me see what you mean.  I assumed I would still have to handle the recursion myself since I cannot simply loop through `other` and check values.  The values of `other` could be other dicts.  I want to just compare the values once everything is boiled down to non-sequence types.

Comment: actually I responded too soon.  I think I understand what you mean.  I will need to compare each dict and can just look for `float` instances in the values and compare those and default to the regular comparison in other situations.  A code snippet would still be useful to make sure I'm on the right track.

Comment: What's the proper way to post code in a comment here?  I got something like what I think you were alluding to: http://dpaste.com/842289/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the kind of thing I meant. (Though that should be `self.iteritems()` in the for loop :-). The inequality on line 11 will trigger recursive comparison if the values are dictionaries.

Comment: But start by comparing `len(self) == len(other)`; otherwise you'll never notice if `other` has extra keys. Etc... the downside of this approach is you have to debug the full comparison logic.

Comment: I want recursive comparison of dicts though.  This revised solution seems to work (minimal testing): http://dpaste.com/842328/

Comment: You're confusing me again: What did I say that suggests non-recursive comparison?

Comment: Looked at your code. If you use `mydict` while creating your nested dicts, you won't need to convert them on the fly. The old version was already recursive.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read your previous post regarding the recursion.  The scenario I'm using this in doesn't make it easy to make those nested dicts the new class so converting on the fly is a necessary evil at this point.