# Compare Two Dictionaries - Floating Point

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this for sometime, tried searching internet and refering some books, yet have not be able to find a solution.

There is one solution proposed here but not sure if there is any other simpler approach. 
Refer: [Comparing Python dicts with floating point values included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749218/comparing-python-dicts-with-floating-point-values-included)

Hope you can give some pointers.

**Background:**
Have dict_A which comes with a {key:{key:{key:[value]}}} relationship. This dict_A will go through an iterative process to optimise its value based on several constraints and an optimization objective. Will stop the optimizing process only when the final optimized dict i.e dict_B2 is equal with the dict optimized one cycle before i.e dict_B1. This gives an impression the dict would not be able to be optimized further and this is used to break the iterative cycle.

**Question:**
As the dicts value contain float number, some stored values get changed, perhaps because dictionary stores value in binary format. Do refer to example below, the variation of the first float value in the dictionary.

```
dict_B1 = {0: {36: {3: [-1], 12: [0.074506333542951425]}}, 1: {36: {2: [-1], 16: [0.048116666666666676], 17: [-1]}}, 2: {}, 3: {36: {5: [-1], 6: [-1], 15: [0.061150932060349471]}}}
dict_B2 = {0: {36: {3: [-1], 12: [0.074506333542951439]}}, 1: {36: {2: [-1], 16: [0.048116666666666676], 17: [-1]}}, 2: {}, 3: {36: {5: [-1], 6: [-1], 15: [0.061150932060349471]}}}
```

If I use the below, the interative process goes infinite loop and does not break,

```
if (dict_B1==dict_B2):
   Exit
```

or,

```
if (cmp(dict_B1,dict_B2)):
   Exit
```

Is there any other way to compare the dictionaries say, compare with 15 floating point precision from the 18 floating point precision values ?

I tried storing lesser precision values floats in the dictionary. The problem still persist.

Hope you can assist to point me to the right direction.

**Update 1: Jakub's Suggestion**

Jakub's suggestion is good. I can create two intermediary lists i.e List_B1 and List_B2 to store the floats, these will be used for comparison and as a flag to decide when to break the iterative process.

The below is the code used to test the case. The second item in List_B2 is purposely altered so the value is way above the precision threshold.

```
def is_equal(floats_a, floats_b, precision=1e-15):
    return all((abs(a-b) < precision) for a, b in izip(floats_a, floats_b))

List_B1=[0.074506333542951425,0.048116666666666676,0.061150932060349471]
List_B2=[0.074506333542951439,9.048116666666666676,0.061150932060349471]

print "is_equal(List_B1,List_B2):",is_equal(List_B1,List_B2)

for a, b in izip(List_B1, List_B2):
    print a,b, (abs(a-b) < 1e-15)
```

Results:

```
is_equal(List_B1,List_B2): True

0.074506333543 0.074506333543 True
0.0481166666667 9.04811666667 False
0.0611509320603 0.0611509320603 True
```

Strangely `is_equal` function always returns `TRUE` which is not correct but when disected the code, it works correctly. Perhaps `return all` is doing an `OR` rather than an `AND`. Still troubleshooting this.

Do share if you have any hints. Will continue to work to solve this. Thanks to Jakub and Julien for all your guidance so far.

rgds
Saravanan K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When comparing floating points, always keep in mind that floats are not of infinite precision and accumulate errors. What you are really interested is if two floats are close enough, not if they are equal

If you want to test if two lists of floats are equal, I would do

```
def is_equal(floats_a, floats_b, precision=1e-15):
    return all((abs(a-b) < precision) for a, b in izip(floats_a, floats_b))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jakub M. Have tested this and have presented my updates as above.Will continue to work on this and update all

Answer (score 1):

As you explained, your code checks that the computed solution is equal to the previous step result. The problem might be that your algorithm oscillate between two (or more) solutions which are really close from each other.

So I think you can either:

- Store several previous results, to check whether you have entered a loop. The problem would be to know how many previous solutions you need to store.
- Or, as suggested by Jakub and by the post you pointed out, you can check if dict_B1 is within a certain range of dict_B2.

The second solution is painful in your case because your structure is way too complex. If you don't want to break all your code, you can replace `[value]` in `{key:{key:{key:[value]}}}` by a custom list-of-float class which redefine the `__eq__()` operator to check equality within a certain range.

Comment: Thanks Julien. Exploring Jakub's suggestion, its seems simpler. If stuck will try yours

Answer (score 1):

**`np.allclose`** is a convenient function to compare two lists of floats.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.allclose(List_B1, List_B2)
False
```

> numpy.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)
>
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))`